# what is this capacitor 220 HFP 1J9

Tags: capacitor

I have a small buck dc-dc voltage converter that has two aluminium body capacitors mounted on the pcb surface. The top reads something like this:
220
HFP
1J9

Here's a photo of it... [image]

I want to know what is the max voltage for this capacitor. I see similar circuit boards that have 35v or 50v capacitors (mostly 35v) but how do I know the voltage rating of this capacitor.

I understand the meaning of 220 that is 220uf but what does HFP and 1J9 means?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome! It might be helpful to provide a well-focused photo of any and all markings on the part. You can provide a link to it.

Comment: added picture for it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The photo is helpful. I suspect it's a Chinese part that is numbered similarly to the [Panasonic FP](http://industrial.panasonic.com/jp/i/29880/V_E/V_E.pdf) series.

[image]

That would make it a 220\$\mu\$F/50V 105°C RoHS low-impedance part, 
size code "G" (10mm⌀\$\times 10.2\$mm tall)

Of course if it's not a genuine Panasonic part (and I don't think it is, the markings don't look like the Panasonic parts I have) the characteristics may not be the same (and chances are they will be, at best, equal).